# Redrawing a key on top of a D3 projection after transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I'm working with a D3 map projection similar to [Mike Bostock's Choropleth seen here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606).

The issue I'm having is that I've added a transition; and when I transition the projection, the map key (seen in the top right corner) is being covered by the background color of the map.

I know I probably just need to redraw the g layer after the transition, but I'm not able to get that working as expected.

I'm originally drawing the key on the map with the following code:

```
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "key")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");

g.selectAll("rect")
  .data(color.range().map(function(d) {
      d = color.invertExtent(d);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 350 + (i * 30)})
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { console.log(d[1]); return color(d[1]); });

g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "caption")
    .attr("x", x.range()[0])
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("Number of Licensed Establishments");

    g.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickSize(13)
        .tickValues(color.domain()))
      .select(".domain")
        .remove();
```

Then I'm transitioning the projection with this code (which also works fine).

```
path = d3.geoPath(projection);
    svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(2000).attr("d", path);
```

But the key gets covered.  I've tried redrawing it like this:

```
g.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");
```

It doesn't do anything though.  What step am I missing to correctly redraw that g layer on top?

Comment: Transitioning elements shouldn't change draw order - I think it is likely that the key is behind the features to start with (it is just that no part of the feature overlaps the key prior to the transition, and therefore the key is visible). Have you tried something like: svg.select("#key").raise(), or, better, g.raise() (given your key lives in g).

Comment: Well, the way I was thinking about it was that the map key needed to be redrawn (last), after the transition, so that it would land on top.  Since there's no z-index in svg's and `svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)` is redrawing the projection path.  Is that not necessary?

Comment: `svg.select("#key").raise()` did work, although it was actually `svg.select(".key").raise()` since this was a class not an id label.  Took me a couple minutes to figure that change out.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. g.raise() should work as well, as the select(".key") returns a selection that is the same as the selection contained in var `g`

Comment: I've tested it every which way and it looks like the perfect solution. Thx. Feel free to add as an answer if you want, it certainly solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitioning a path shouldn't change where it appears in the DOM. Transitioning element attributes with d3 modifies that element in place in the DOM. The following example should demonstrate this (path is appended first and should be behind the text, the path then transitions its `d` attribute through two d3 symbol paths remaining behind the text):

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',400).attr('height',200);

var cross = "M-21.213203435596427,-7.0710678118654755L-7.0710678118654755,-7.0710678118654755L-7.0710678118654755,-21.213203435596427L7.0710678118654755,-21.213203435596427L7.0710678118654755,-7.0710678118654755L21.213203435596427,-7.0710678118654755L21.213203435596427,7.0710678118654755L7.0710678118654755,7.0710678118654755L7.0710678118654755,21.213203435596427L-7.0710678118654755,21.213203435596427L-7.0710678118654755,7.0710678118654755L-21.213203435596427,7.0710678118654755Z";

var star = "M0,-29.846492114305246L6.700954981042517,-9.223073285798176L28.38570081386192,-9.223073285798177L10.8423729164097,3.5229005144437298L17.543327897452222,24.146319342950797L1.7763568394002505e-15,11.400345542708891L-17.543327897452215,24.1463193429508L-10.842372916409698,3.522900514443731L-28.38570081386192,-9.22307328579817L-6.7009549810425195,-9.223073285798176Z";

var wye = "M8.533600336205877,4.926876451265144L8.533600336205877,21.9940771236769L-8.533600336205877,21.9940771236769L-8.533600336205877,4.9268764512651435L-23.31422969000131,-3.6067238849407337L-14.78062935379543,-18.387353238736164L0,-9.853752902530289L14.78062935379543,-18.387353238736164L23.31422969000131,-3.6067238849407337Z"

var symbol = svg.append('path')
   .attr('transform','translate(100,100)')
   .attr('d', cross )
   .attr("fill","orange");
   
var text = svg.append('text')
  .attr('x', 100)
  .attr('y', 105)
  .style('text-anchor','middle')
  .text('THIS IS SOME TEXT')
   
symbol.transition()
  .delay(2000)
  .attr('d', star )
  .duration(2000)
  .transition()
  .attr('d', wye )
  .duration(2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Given your example, it is likely that the key is initially rendered behind the features of the map - only there is no overlap between the two. Each appears as intended. When transitioning, with say a zoom, the features overlap and the key is hidden. As noted in the comments, try `g.raise()` or `d3.select(".key").raise()` to move the key to the bottom of the parent container, effectively lifting it above other svg elements (as elements are rendered in the order they appear in the DOM, as close as we get to a z-index in svg). You should only need to apply .raise() once - as the transition won't change the ordering, or alternatively, ensure that the key is appended to the svg last.